# JSON Literal Manupulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON literal as given below.

```
{
  "GB":[
        {"name":"Bob","score":9},
        {"name":"Joe","score":6},
        {"name":"Tom","score":7}
  ],
  "GP":[
        {"name":"Mahesh","score":19},
        {"name":"Anand","score":62},
        {"name":"Sawapnil","score":76}
  ]
}
```

How can edit or remove from above JSON. Like, If GB -> Score: 7 to Score: 73 and 
remove GP -> {"name":"Anand","score":62}

Comment: Are you asking how to load this JSON text from a file into a structure in JavaScript and modify that structure? JSON is a text format, so you need to 1) parse the text into a data structure, 2) modify the data structure, and 3) re-serialize the modified structure back into JSON text. It's not clear which of these steps to want to do and/or need help with.

Comment: Question is not clear :(

Comment: There isn't really something like a JSON "literal". You either have JSON (a data exchange format), or you have JavaScript object literal.

Comment: If this is just about processing JavaScript objects / arrays, it's probably a duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196) and [How to remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767325/218196)

Answer (score 1):

You turn it into an array and then back to json.

```
var arr = $.map(obj, function(el) { return el });

arr['GB'][3]['score'] = 73;

var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

or as a javascript object:

```
var jsonobj = JSON.parse(json);

jsonobj.GB[3].score = 73;

var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: You're right, its a javascript object parsed from a json, edited

Comment: Not working at my end..And also how to remove it as i mention in the question.

Comment: How to  remove GP -> {"name":"Anand","score":62} dynamically.